# Getting product's combination attributes in PrestaShop

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop

I am trying to display Product's combination attributes (like "size") in the front-office of PrestaShop.

**When I say "combination attributes" I mean this (selected Size : S, for example):**

[image: Size : S]

**I tried doing it this way:**

[image: Code sample]

**But all I get is this:**

[image]

There is no "size" key in the results and I am a little bit lost. I am trying to send this data to the `CartController` (which I will override) and display the selected size in the cart. Can you help me with retrieving this data, please?

Comment: you can see product.tpl, in which there's attributes listboxs, try to find <!-- attributes -->

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve it :).